# How to escape two bash variables when echoing them

Tags: bash, echo

I want to echo a text like this:

```
"I'm going to bed at "$'\cc3'"$var"$'\cc'
```

Sometimes it happens that the `$var` variable begins with a number and Bash is simply concatenating it or whatever. How could I escape the `$var` so it is separated but without a space between them?

Comment: Can you show an assignment to `var` which demonstrates the problem?  What are you expecting the ANSI-C Quoting that you're using to generate?

Answer (score 2):

The [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) mechanism in Bash uses `\cx` to generate <kbd>Control-X</kbd>.  Your use of `$'\cc3'` generates a <kbd>Control-C</kbd> (aka `\003` or `\x03`) character followed by a digit 3.

Superficially, then, you want:

```
var=01:15
echo "I'm going to bed at "$'\cc'"$var"$'\cc'
```

which surrounds the time with <kbd>Control-C</kbd> characters (though quite why you want that, I'm not clear).  If you're after a Unicode character U+0CC3 (KANNADA VOWEL SIGN VOCALIC R —  ೃ — if you've got good Unicode support), then you need Bash 4.x and `$'\ucc3'`.

If you're after something else, you need to explain what you're trying to echo with the ANSI-C Quoting.

Comment: yes thats a point to generate a control+c effect, i'm using bash to send text to irc through an other programs and to use the mirc color codes on irc you need a control+c and some numbers after that, for reference http://www.ircbeginner.com/ircinfo/colors.html

Comment: @rsz: Curious, the reference you show points to various control characters, but not Control-C.  However, if you output `\ck1` for black, and and the time is `13:15`, then the output could be interpreted as Control-K and 11 for aqua (and 3:15 for the time). You can get teal (10) fairly easily if you use 24-hour clocks; I suppose if you don't use leading zeroes, then values between 1:00 and 6:00 can leave things open to misinterpretation. How to resolve? Tricky… The simplest is probably to colour the space (12 = royal blue): `echo "I'm going to bed at"$'\ck12'" $var"$'\co'`. This is unambiguous.

Comment: yes but there will be a space then and i don't need that space, that's the problem i'm struggling with

Comment: You need a space between 'at' and the time; this one has coloured text and works correctly.  Your alternative can't be made unambiguous — this is the proverbial rock and hard place.  The colourizing mechanism is not well designed in the sense that there isn't an unambiguous end to the colour coding string.  That means you have to compensate for the bad design.  If your terminal uses UTF-8, you could use a non-spacing character (for example, U+FEFF, ZERO WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE, created with `$'\uFFEF'`).

Comment: hmm, maybe a question which is not related to bash but hopefully you can answer it, in python i have the same problem, is there anything to  make it happen in python to not append the variables together? cuz if yes i will write it in that

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the choice of language to generate the string; the problem is in the IRC client that consumes it.  As I said, the notation used is ambiguous.  It would have been better to use a hex digit for the colour, for instance, so that there was no way that the colour could be confused with the following text.  But that was not the way it was designed, so you're stuck with it.

Comment: thanks, i was thinking about it too, but didn't come out with an answer so i'm gonna rethink this whole and thanks for all of you

Answer (score 0):

You could try sending the control-c using the `\nnn` format instead of `\c`:

```
echo $'I\'m going to bed at \003'"$var"$'\003'
```

(I changed the quoting slightly just to reduce the the number of context switches used to build the string.)

Or, save the control-c character in a variable:

```
cc=$'\cc'
echo "I'm going to bed at $cc$var$cc"
```

Comment: are you telling me that this version will not append together the CTRL+3 (\cc3) and the for example $var="00011dd" together. I mean if we echo this then it will be this \cc300011dd and that's the problem i'm struggling with, it is appending together and the expression thinks that i'm not sending \cc3 but \cc300 and whatever after this until this is accepting the numbers. So it's added together