# How to separate variables without spaces

Tags: bash, shell, printf

My question is similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037718/how-to-escape-two-bash-variables-when-echoing-them), but not really.

The issue is that I have variables in my script that will echo/printf control characters directly next to the previous. Unfortunately I have to put spaces between the variables or everything gets misinterpreted, but that's not going to work either, as I can't have spaces between them.

```
str="25 cents"
one=1
two=2             

printf "\x3${one},${two}${str}\x30"\
```

(without spaces this string messes up)

```
printf "\x3${one},${two}%s\x30" "${str}" # outputs "5 cents"
```

So it ends up being either `" 25 cents "` (wrong), or `"5 cents"` (wrong x 2)... It should be:

```
25 cents
```

I've tried just about everything, escaping the variables, putting them in quotes and no luck. Evidently there's a correct way to handle this that I'm unaware of, so any help is great - thanks.

Comment: I do not understand.  Can you give and example WITHOUT the `one` and `two` variables (just use the digits), so I can see what you are trying to do with the escape sequences?

Comment: @Jack: Sure, `printf "\x31,2<String>\x30"`... so what happens is that any numbers in the front or back of `<String>` (25 cents) causes issues for the escape/control codes (`\x31,2` would become `\x31,225 cents ...`).

Comment: I think you need to reread the ansi colour code sequences. There is an `m` after the numbers, and the sequence is introduced by ESC [ (eg. `\x1b[31,2m`).

Comment: **NOT clear enough** but may you should use `echo` not `printf`. Since when you use `%s` with `printf` of course you have to separate your string with a space then pass it to `printf`

Comment: Please clarify whether the output should be `25 cents` or `225 cents`.

Comment: Also, using the names given in [`man ascii`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html) , please specify which control characters should be output.  That is, if the goal is to output ASCII hex code `03`, that'd be an `ETX` char, whereas an ASCII hex code `31` would be the `1` char.

Comment: @rici: This is color coding is done through IRC, so those particular ANSI codes will not work.

Comment: You don't know *who* down-voted you or why. And making such assumptions and swearing at folks who often bend over backwards to help *in their free time, on their own and for free* won't help either.

Comment: Well, I cannot say exactly how to fix your problem, because I cannot reproduce it.  However, I suggest you NOT use variables in the format string.  So it would look something like this: `printf "\x3%1d,%1d%s\x30" "$one" "$two" "$str"`  If you need a non-printing character somewhere, try `\x0`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is insert [mIRC colour codes](http://www.mirc.com/colors.html) into a string -- and you would have made it easier to be helped if you had said so -- then you need to be aware of two things:

1. The C-style hexadecimal escapes interpreted by Gnu  `printf` have the format `\x` followed by *two* hexadecimal digits. (You can use just one digit, but only if the next character is not a hexadecimal digit. So it's better to think of it as always being two digits.) A control-C (character code 3) is written `\x03`. `x30` through `\x39` are the character codes for the digits `0` through `9`. The translation of the escape code is done by printf, not by the shell, so parameter substitution happens first. So if the value of `$one` is one, `printf "\x3${one}"` will be expanded to `printf "\x31"` by the shell, and then `printf` will print the digit `1`. I presume that is not what you want, since there are obviously much less round-about ways to insert the value of a variable, which don't limit the variable to be a single decimal digit.

   Not all `printf` implementations handle hexadecimal escapes, and not all shells have a built-in `printf`. So while you can use `\x03` with bash, you might find that it is not portable. All `printf` implementations should handle octal escapes, though, and `3` is still `3` in octal, but now you need three digits: `\003`.
2. The mIRC colour codes have the form control-C followed by up to two numbers separated by a comma. These numbers have a maximum of two digits, and if the next character after the colour code is a digit, you must use the two-digit form. (Coincidentally similar to the hex escape codes above, but it is truly just a coincidence.) So if you wanted the text `25` with foreground colour 3 and background colour 1, you would need to send `^C1,0225^C`; if you sent `^C1,225^C`, that would be interpreted as foreground colour 1 and background colour 25 (which is not a valid colour code), with the text being `5`.

   This is mentioned in the mIRC documentation linked above:

   > Note: if you want to color text that begins with numbers, this syntax requires that you specify the color value as two digits.

So a better `printf` invocation might be:

```
printf "\003%02d,%02d%s\003" "$one" "$two" "$str"
```

---

Note: It is, of course, possible that my guess about what string you are seeking to produce is completely wrong; it is just a guess based on an off-hand comment which was not deleted. If so, and if you are serious about getting your question answered, I strongly suggest you provide a clearer explanation of precisely what byte-string you are attempting to produce with your `printf` statement.